# Can ADAL be used with Azure AD (Connect) Passthrough Authentication for Integrated Auth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

When calling AcquireToken I get the error that silent authentication can not be used for managed users

I have the following code that reproduces the error:

```
    $nuGetPackages = "$env:temp\packages"
    $clientVersion = '3.14.2'
    $libPath = Join-Path $nuGetPackages "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.$clientVersion\lib"

    if (!(Test-Path $libPath)) {
        Write-Host "Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory module"
        Install-Package -Name 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' -RequiredVersion $clientVersion -ProviderName NuGet -Destination $nuGetPackages -Source http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -Force | Out-Null
    }

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    $tenantName = [string]::Join('.',([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current.DistinguishedName.Split(',') |? { $_.Split('=')[0] -eq 'dc' } |% { $_.Split('=')[1] }))
    $authority = "https://login.windows.net/$tenantName"
    $resourceAppIdUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
    $clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2" # common app id

    Get-ChildItem $libPath -Filter net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll |% { [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_.FullName) | Out-Null }

    try {
        $creds = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList $env:USERNAME@$tenantName
        $creds.UserAuthType
        $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
        $task = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdUri, $clientId, $creds)
        $task.Wait()
        $authResult = $task.Result
        $authResult
        return $authResult.AccessToken
    } catch {
        throw $_.Exception.ToString()
    }
```

Produces the error

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: password_required_for_managed_user: Password is required for managed user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true silent authentication like with ADFS (meaning it pops up a windows and cannot be used with non-interactive service accounts), but using PromptBehavior.None or Auto allows the pass-through (or password sync) Azure Seamless SSO to work (no password prompt)

Answer (score 0):

This error means you didn't provider the password for this method. If you want to use the **Resource owner password credentials flow** to acquire the access token, we should provider both username and password via `UserPasswordCredential` class.

Here is the code sample which works well for me:

```
$nuGetPackages = "$env:temp\packages"
$clientVersion = '3.14.2'
$libPath = Join-Path $nuGetPackages "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.$clientVersion\lib"

if (!(Test-Path $libPath)) {
    Write-Host "Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory module"
    Install-Package -Name 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' -RequiredVersion $clientVersion -ProviderName NuGet -Destination $nuGetPackages -Source http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -Force | Out-Null
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$tenantName = [string]::Join('.',([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current.DistinguishedName.Split(',') |? { $_.Split('=')[0] -eq 'dc' } |% { $_.Split('=')[1] }))
$authority = "https://login.windows.net/$tenantName"
$resourceAppIdUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
$clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2" # common app id

Get-ChildItem $libPath -Filter net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll |% { [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_.FullName) | Out-Null }

try {     
    $creds = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential" -ArgumentList '{username}', '{password}'
    #$creds.UserAuthType
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $task = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authContext,$resourceAppIdUri, $clientId, $creds)
    #$task = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdUri, $clientId, $creds)
    $task.Wait()
    $authResult = $task.Result
    $authResult
    return $authResult.AccessToken
} catch {
    throw $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

Comment: Please see that I'm trying to accomplish integrated auth, which works fine with adfs - there should be no username or password required

Comment: How id you intact with ADFS? Based on the code you were using `$creds`(`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential`) providing the username. If I misunderstood, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: If you provide no username or password it uses integrated authentication

Comment: To narrow down this issue, I suggest that using the Fiddler to capture the request to see the difference between ADFS and Azure AD. BTW, does the code in the post work for you?

Comment: Yes it does with ADFS

Comment: It does a realm discovery REST request which returns that the user is managed and then throws that error

Comment: If I understood correctly, when the code request the token, it using the **Resource owner password credentials flow**, you can check the value of parameter `grant_type`(it should be `password`) in the token request. Based on my understanding, if the user is a managed user, the token request will no be redirect to the ADFS and in this secnario, we need to provide the username/password via  **Resource owner password credentials flow**(refer [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/)).

Comment: Does the code works for you when you using the `UserPasswordCredential` to provide the username/password instead of using `UserCredential`?

Comment: Yes - but the goal here is not to provide a password